# Merge username and time in long-format data

Tags: r

I don't why I didn't get the results with four conditions for the mutate function.
I don't why I didn't get the results with four conditions for the mutate function.
I don't why I didn't get the results with four conditions for the mutate function.
I don't why I didn't get the results with four conditions for the mutate function.

```
twitter_wide <- twitter_d %>% mutate(
  Condition = ifelse(Date >= "20219-05-1" & Date <= "2020-03-31", "T1", 
                     ifelse(Date >= "2020-04-01" & Date <= "2020-06-30", "T2", 
                            ifelse(Date >= "2020-07-1" & Date <= "2020-12-31", "T3", 
                            ifelse(Date >= "2021-01-01" & Date <= "2021-04-30", "T4", NA)))
) %>% 
  group_by(username, age, Condition) %>% 
  summarise(compound = mean(`compound`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Condition, names_prefix = "", values_from = compound)
```

```
> twitter_wide <- twitter_d %>% mutate(
+   Condition = ifelse(Date >= "20219-05-1" & Date <= "2020-03-31", "T1", 
+                      ifelse(Date >= "2020-04-01" & Date <= "2020-06-30", "T2", 
+                             ifelse(Date >= "2020-07-1" & Date <= "2020-12-31", "T3", 
+                             ifelse(Date >= "2021-01-01" & Date <= "2021-04-30", "T4", NA)))
+ ) %>% 
+   group_by(username, age, Condition) %>% 
+   summarise(compound = mean(`compound`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
+   pivot_wider(names_from = Condition, names_prefix = "", values_from = compound)
+
```

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'username', 'time', create a logical condition in `mutate` to return `NA` `if` `all` the values in 'score' are `NA` or `else` take the `mean` of 'score'

```
library(dplyr)
data_d %>%
  group_by(username, time) %>%
  mutate(mean_score = if(all(is.na(score))) NA_real_ 
        else mean(score, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Another option is to use `mean_` from `hablar` which will return `NA` in case all the values are NA

```
library(hablar)
data_d %>%
   group_by(username, time) %>%
   mutate(mean_score = mean_(score))
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's update code, we can use `case_when`

```
twitter_wide <- twitter_d %>% 
     mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
  Condition = case_when(Date >= as.Date("20219-05-1") & 
                  Date <= as.Date("2020-03-31") ~ "T1", 
                Date >= as.Date("2020-04-01") & 
                  Date <= as.Date("2020-06-30") ~ "T2", 
                Date >= as.Date("2020-07-1") & 
                  Date <= as.Date("2020-12-31")~ "T3", 
                Date >= as.Date("2021-01-01") &
                  Date <= as.Date("2021-04-30") "T4"))
```